# How to stretch single element in hbox layout?

Tags: extjs4

How to tell extjs4 stretch just one element in `hbox` layout?

For example I have the following layout:

```js
{
    flex: 1,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        flex: 1,
        // GRID, needs to be stretched
    }, {
        // button, don't stretch
    }, {
        // another button, don't stretch
    }]
}
```

In the code above I have all elements (including buttons) are stretched. Is it possible in box layouts?

I can, of course, wrap buttons in the hbox container, but I don't like this solution.

Comment: Currently there's no way to specify the align config on a per item basis.

Comment: Ok, so is there any other way to stretch one element to max width? `anchor` doesn't work here because I don't want to use numeric negative offsets.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround you could use is to give the buttons a `maxHeight`, since constrains always "win".

```js
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        renderTo: document.body,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            flex: 1,
            title: 'A panel'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'B1',
            maxHeight: 25
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'B2',
            maxHeight: 25
        }]
    })
});
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I've meant vbox, not hbox. Vertically arranged items, top one has full allowed width  (i.e. stretched)  and the next two — only required width (with white space at the right). And grid also should be maximized vertically (it's done by `flex:1` in a grid definition).

Comment: The same thing applies, if you configure them with a `maxWidth`. Otherwise, as you said, you could wrap them in a container and let them auto size.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know buttons size unfortunately, they are localized so width is not fixed. So I think the wrapping is the only working way.

Answer (score 0):

Single element can be stretched. Sample [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ohp) explains the stretching of components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).